# COUNTIFS, number, wildcard, formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, regex, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using this formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(EXCEL_TAB!$A$1:$A$999999", "*"&"#_CELL_VALUE"&"*")
```

How can I specify that that for #_CELL_VALUE, this can be any number followed by _CELL_VALUE? The reason is because the data has the values S_CELL_VALUE (the letter S) and #_CELL_VALUE (# is any number). So I need to differentiate them.

```
    Sample Data
RS_CELL_VALUE, 11_CELL_VALUE
RS_CELL_VALUE
11_CELL_VALUE
12_CELL_VALUE
13_CELL_VALUE, RS_CELL_VALUE
```

Attempt code

```
=COUNTA(REGEXMATCH(Data!A1:A999999, "*[0-9]_CELL_VALUE*"))
```

Comment: `REGEXMATCH` is not an excel formula and Google question belong on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(EXCEL_TAB!$A$1:$A$999999,"*"&"&SEQUENCE(1,10,0,1)&"_CELL_VALUE"))
```

and if you do not have `SEQUENCE()` you can use `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` instead. (I prefer it since I want to get used to using it and because sometimes it helps coerce `SPILL` functionality where it wouldn't otherwise occur. But the above array constant isn't hard to type so... and if one doesn't have it...)

Putting the whole array of possible variations to check for is what makes it work, however one does that (`SEQUENCE()` or otherwise).

`COUNTIFS()` should be totalling up the number of successes but seems not to be doing so. It IS, however, noting the successes, so `SUM()` is able to add those notations up for the result needed. PROBABLY due to `SPILL` functionality, it is indeed doing that, but for each individual value in the array constant being checked (not each individual cell in the range). So you have 10 (in this case) individual results and if any of the cells have the same contents, say three of them, one of those 10 "buckets" would report "3" via `COUNTIFS()`. Since you want to know for ALL the 10 possibilities, summing them all not only gives you that single summed value, but reduces your cell "footprint" back to the single cell your formula is in rather than it being a 10 cell range of results that might be trying to SPILL overtop something else giving an error.

Downside (potentially):  AS WRITTEN, `33_CELL_VALUE` and `3_CELL_VALUE` BOTH count since the initial `*` allows for the first 3 in `33_etc.` to be part of it so the formula sees no difference between those two things. If that matters, though I imagine it doesn't, one would have to reconsider that portion of the condition being presented to `COUNTIFS()`.